# minify the signalr/hubs file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr, minify

I'm using signalr in my app and am referencing it like so:

`<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Of course signalr is generated javascript dynamically on the fly.  When I run yslow to better the performance of my web application it complains that singalr/hubs is not minified.  Surely when I click on the link it shows the js, small snippet sample:

```
/*!
 * ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library v2.1.1
 * http://signalr.net/
 *
 * Copyright Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the Apache 2.0
 * https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/LICENSE.md
 *
 */

/// <reference path="..\..\SignalR.Client.JS\Scripts\jquery-1.6.4.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.signalR.js" />
(function ($, window, undefined) {
    /// <param name="$" type="jQuery" />
    "use strict";

    if (typeof ($.signalR) !== "function") {
        throw new Error("SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.");
    }

    var signalR = $.signalR;

    function makeProxyCallback(hub, callback) {
        return function () {
            // Call the client hub method
            callback.apply(hub, $.makeArray(arguments));
        };
    }

    function registerHubProxies(instance, shouldSubscribe) {
        var key, hub, memberKey, memberValue, subscriptionMethod;
```

How can I minify this file if it is generated automagically?

## Edit

Let me also clarify I am using `lcsk` which can be found [here](https://github.com/dstpierre/lcsk), which uses signalr.  In this package there is a startup.cs file which looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(RIMS.LCSK.Startup))]

    namespace RIMS.LCSK
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                app.MapSignalR();
            }
        }
    }
```

Do I need to somehow tell it to minify at this point?  I've seen this:

[SignalR hub.js minify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035759/signalr-hub-js-minify) (but this seems to be using a global.asax file) And I've also seen this:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2403

But I'm uncertain where I need to do any of this with what I have.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [extensibility guide](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Extensibility). It lists an [`IJavaScriptMinifier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.ijavascriptminifier%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) interface you can implement to do what you're looking for. (And maybe couple it with the Optimization/Bundling library or another 3rd party minifier).

Comment: I saw that, see my edit, however I'm not sure where to even implement this interface.  Can you look at my edits to see my troubles?

Answer (score 1):

As the extensibility guide suggests you should implement `IJavaScriptMinifier` which consists of just one `Minify` method. Afterwards, provide your `IJavaScriptMinifier` implementing class to the [SignalR dependency injection pipeline](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) and SignalR will take care of using the minifier when it needs to.

Here's an example of a class implementing `IJavaScriptMinifier`, where `Minifier` is the [Microsoft Ajax Minifier](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxMin/).

```
public class SignalrJavascriptMinifier : IJavaScriptMinifier
{
    public string Minify(string source)
    {
        return new Minifier().MinifyJavaScript(source);
    }
}
```